# Is it possible to add High Charts categories on each other

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

Is it possible to add high charts series/categories on top of each other?

For example, assume that I have 5 categories (very low, low, medium, high, very high) and I have 12 months of data for these categories. Currently, I have 1 month of data displayed.

So let's say for June, the series order is listed as 12 (very low), 3 (low), 6 (medium), 16 (high), 1 (very high).

And for May, the series order is listed as 16 (very low), 3 (low), 9 (medium), 1 (high), 6 (very high).

Is there a way to have these categories stack on top of each other so that if I selected the range of May through June, the final chart will be 28 (very low), 6 (low), 15 (medium), 17 (high), 7 (very high)?

I've taken a look at range selector and it kinda makes sense how I'd attack it that way, but I'm just not sure how I would get the categories to add to each other. Thanks!

BTW, the data is listed in a Json object received from a sql server query. 
If that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you looked at group categories? http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

Comment: As in a stacked column or area chart...?  Have you looked at the demos and the documentation?  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked | http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked | http://www.highcharts.com/demo/